# Different CSS for subpage doesn't load

Tags: html, css, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have:

- website.com/index.html
- website.com/style.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon.png">
```

Everything works fine.

And:

- website.com/page/index.html
- website.com/page/style.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon.png">
```

The favicon loads but the CSS is not showing, I just see the HTML text of the page.

Now, before I forced HTTPS using the .htaccess and an Let's Encrypt SSL. I could load the page/style.css on the http://, but it never worked on https.

What am I missing?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: use an absolute path to your stylesheet (`/stylesheet.css`) - the current path is relative to the url serving it so when you go to a sub directory (ie page/index) it won't find the css file as it's not in page/

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for the quick reply! Update on the issue: I was struggling with this ~4hours ago, now I load my website and the css works fine! Is there some caching I don't know of? Maybe a way to force a refresh... Shift+F5 didn't do the trick. Someone else recommended I added a / or even ./ to the css href but apparently that doesnt't matter. (also I never got a warning or error, the CSS just didn't appear to load on the page)

Comment: use ctrl f5 to reload the stylesheet (and don't use `./` as that is also relative)